# Looking for KML validator

Tags: kml, data-validation

I'm looking for a KML validator. It appears that the two websites that did this are gone (feedvalidator.org and kmlvalidator.com).

What websites, or other methods, can I use?

Comment: You can try to read the file with ogrinfo. If it succeeds, the file should be valid

Comment: Any XML validator will check it for you

Answer (score 1):

As an "other method" you can use the Teamengine OGC Validator http://cite.opengeospatial.org/teamengine/. It has a KML 2.2 Conformance Test Suite
http://cite.opengeospatial.org/teamengine/about/kml22/2.2/site/.

It is possible to use the installation that is hosted by OGC  or to install Teamengine locally. On-line service requires registration and it does not accept very large files.

Part of a test report as an example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A command-line utility called [XmlValidate](https://github.com/docjason/XmlValidate) validates any XML document with its associated XML Schema. It has an added benefit to pick a directory and recursively validate all KML/KMZs files in that directory and sub-directories.

There is also a kml mode option with `-K` argument to examine any file with a .kml file extension.

```
xv -K data
```

**Example output:**

```
Check: data\bad\badColor.kml
http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2
ERROR: SAXParseException org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 8; columnNumber: 16; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element '{"http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2":color}'. One of '{"http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2":heading, "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2":Icon, "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2":hotSpot, "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2":IconStyleSimpleExtensionGroup, "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2":IconStyleObjectExtensionGroup}' is expected.
Line: 8, column: 16
8: <color>***ff0000</color>
ERROR: SAXParseException org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 8; columnNumber: 16; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element '{"http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2":color}'. One of '{"http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2":heading,
 "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2":Icon,
 "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2":hotSpot,
 "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2":IconStyleSimpleExtensionGroup, 
 "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2":IconStyleObjectExtensionGroup}' is expected.
Line: 8, column: 16
ERROR: SAXParseException org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 8; columnNumber: 30;
cvc-length-valid: Value 'ff0000' with length = '3' is not facet-valid with respect to length '4' for type 'colorType'.
Line: 8, column: 30
ERROR: SAXParseException org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 8; columnNumber: 30;
cvc-type.3.1.3: The value 'ff0000' of element 'color' is not valid.
Line: 8, column: 30
```

This was used in a survey of KML and KMZ files which had its results published in a paper [KML Best Practices for Interoperability](https://www.mitre.org/sites/default/files/pdf/11_3295.pdf) showing 70% of KML documents failed to validate to the KML XML schema.

Only requirement for using XmlValidate is having Java Runtime Environment on your computer.